# xampp and acces Local area network

Tags: xampp, lan

I create a local network between my physical machine (windows) and my virtual machine (Fedorat)
I installed xampp on fedorat and I want to access my web application located in / opt / lampp / htdocs / MyApplication from my physical machine by ip address of the virtual machine
http://192.168.0.2/
But its not working
What changes must I do that on xampp to make it accessible

Answer (score 0):

Is your webserver running and is it possible to access the webserver locally (from your Fedora VM)?

What do you mean by not working? There are so many things that could be wrong... Do you receive a 404? Timeout? Are your machines on the same subnet? Are you able to ping your Fedora machine from Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem once. In my case, it was because of firewall settings.

Try connecting your own machine to a LAN access point in the same router as the VM is connected.

I don't have much tech. background, but maybe if you narrow it to this specific case, someone else can help you.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I ping my VM from my physical machine and it works very well
How long have I install wamp on my physical machine and I set up for access to local network and I accessed from my VM
So the network between two machines running very well
my question is not about the establishment of networks between the two machines but rather how to configure XAMPP that it is accessible by
other machine in network
(I was already a problem on windows with wamp parail I solved by configuring wamp but I recall more of what I did)